# How to recover the deleted files in ubuntu 18.04 lts server

Tags: data-recovery

I have deleted a folder in Ubuntu 18.04 lts server, i cant find a proper solution to recover the deleted folder and files. Is there any proper solution to recover the files?

Comment: The proper solution is to restore the file from your backups. This is why we love backups. While the GUI has a recoverable Trash Can, the shell does not - deleted is deleted. If you are in that condition, then STOP using that disk right now. On a different system, look up data recovery methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  i can create a new files instead of the deleted file, Just to know if there are any methods.

Comment: No recovery-from-deletion methods in a stock install of Ubuntu Server. There are a couple methods you can install, and recovery from backups of course.